# How to wait for a property of an element whose value is returned after the page loads in casperjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm scraping a site where there is a hidden field called say "abc", and the body tag of the site looks something like this

```
<body onload="fnAssignValue();">
     <input type="hidden" value="" id="abc" name="abc"/>
</body>
```

Hence initially when the page loads I have the abc value as empty when i use the casper js code

```
this.getElementAttribute('#abc', 'value')
```

to get the value as here the function on body load actually assigns the value to element after the server call.

I tried doing

```
casper.then(function(){
   this.waitFor(function check() {
      return this.evaluate(function() {
         return document.querySelector("#abc").value.length > 2;
      });
   },function then() {    // step to execute when check() is ok
     console.log('yes');
   },function timeout() { // step to execute if check has failed
     console.log('no');
  });
});
```

But still was unable to get the value even with timeout also.

Can anyone please help ??

Comment: @ArtjomB you were right i found a page error all the resources are loading except for the server call which loads the data for abc value it throws error as : Unable to load resource (#17URL:https://xxx.xx..xx/xxxxx.html)
Error code: 299. Description: Error downloading https://xxx.xx..xx/xxxxx.html - server replied: Internal Server Error

any ideas what must have went wrong, I tried to make the same post call from node also but ended with 500

Comment: Please the additional information to your question. But this is still not enough to diagnose the problem. You will have to investigate further yourself.